# SRV record for localhost XMPP

Tags: 14.04, dns, xmpp

My question is how to add the SRV records for XMPP to my localhost domain (dns configuration)?. Where exactly do I have to add and What tool do I need to perform this?

I am new to DNS configuration filed and have looked on internet. But I didn't find what I am looking for.

More specifically:

```
_xmpp-client._tcp.localhost. 18000 IN SRV 0 5 5222 internal.localhost.
_xmpp-server._tcp.localhost. 18000 IN SRV 0 5 5269 internal.localhost.
```

Where to add these SRV records?

For more information https://prosody.im/doc/dns

My xmpp server is running on `localhost` and I want to allow xmpp services to my `internal.localhost` virtual host.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not 100% sure on this, but I believe that you would put the `SRV` entry in `/etc/bind/db.local` which is the `localhost` record. As far as making the edit to the record files, your favorite Terminal text editor (`vi`, `pico`, etc.) executed with `sudo` will be required as the `bind` files are owned by `root`.